The cardinality of specific set $A\subset \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$
Let $A$ be a set of total functions from the naturals to the naturals 
such that for every $f\in A$ there is a finite set $B_f\subset \mathbb{N}$ , such that for every $x\notin B_f$ , $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$.
The question asks about the cardinality of $A$.
I tried the following:
First, notice that $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ , thus $|A|\leq\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\aleph$
Consider the following function $g:\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow A$ :
$\forall f\in \mathbb{N} \ , \ g(f)(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} f(x-1)+1 & x\notin \left \{ 1 \right \} \\ f(x) & x\in \left \{ 1 \right \} \end{matrix}\right.$
It can be shown that $g$ is injective.
This will give according to CSB theorem that $|A|=\aleph$.
The problem with this proof is that I'm assuming that $\exists B_f:B_f=\left \{ 1 \right \}$ ,
and even so, that doesn't mean $\forall B_{f}\ , 1\in B_{f}$.

I imagine that by $\aleph$, you mean $2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$?

$\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$, not "$\aleph$"

@mathcounterexamples.net Yes. $\aleph$ is another notation for $\mathfrak{c}$

@AnneBauval May I ask for your help? I'm really stuck and what I've written here (and in the comments) is the farthest I've come.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number is not "another notation for $\mathfrak{c}$". I'll be back in 2 hours to see if I can help.

Your $h:=g(f)$ satisfies $h(x+1)=f(x)+1$ instead of $h(x+1)=h(x)+1$.

Hint
For $n \in \mathbb N$, let $I_n = \{1, 2, \dots, n\} \subset \mathbb N$, $B_n = \{f \in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} \mid f(m+1)=f(m) + 1 \text{ for } m \notin I_n\}$ and $B = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n$.
You can prove that:

$B_n$ is countable for $n \in \mathbb N$.
Therefore $B$ is countable.
You can find a one-to-one map from $A$ to $B$.

From that, conclude that $\lvert A \rvert = \aleph_0$.
Note: your map $g$ is not well defined.

In order to proof that $B_n$ is countable for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$
, I considered the following bijection $g:B_n \to \times_{1}^{n} \ \mathbb{N}$
$$\forall f\in B_n \ , \ g(f)=\left \langle f(1),...,f(n) \right \rangle$$
From this we get that $|B|=\aleph_0$.
I'm not able to find a bijection from $A$ to $B$

@Daniel A fact to be noticed, is that for $f \in A$, there may be several associated $B_f$. But that doesn't matter. What matters is that if $f \in A$ then $f$ is eventually defined by $f(m+1) = f(m) + 1$.

This inspired me to try the following:
Let $C$ be the set of all finite sequence of $\mathbb{N}$. $|C|=\aleph_0$.
All I was able to find is an injective $g$ from $A$ to $C$ as follows:$$g(f)=\left{\begin{matrix} \left \langle f(1),f(k_1),...,f(k_n) \right \rangle & 1\notin B_f,B_f=\left { k_1,...,k_n \right } \ \left \langle f(k_1),...,f(k_n) \right \rangle & 1\in B_f,B_f=\left { k_1,...,k_n \right } \end{matrix}\right.$$
I will really appreciate if you be able to write formally what you meant.

@Daniel This $g$ (even if you take care to define $B_f$ uniquely) cannot be injective, because it doesn't keep track of who are $k_1,\dots,k_n$ (only their images under $f$). You can remedy this by redefining $g(f)$ as follows: let $k_f$ be the largest integer $k$ such that $f(k+1)\ne f(k)+1$. Then, $g(f):=(f(1),f(2),\dots,f(k_f),f(k_f+1))$.

@AnneBauval Thank you for the insight.
I'm still failing to see the surjective part of $g$.
(I'm assuming $g$ maps $A$ to $C$ (the set of all finite sequence of $\mathbb{N}$)).
The typical proof for surjective (as I'm aware of) is: Let $y\in C$ , i.e. $y$ is some finite sequence.
I need to find an input $f\in A$ s.t $g(f)=y$ but I'm failing to do this because I don't know anything about $B_f$

This $g$ is not surjective (for instance $(1,2)\in C$ has no preimage). I was only correcting your previous comment, where you were claiming to have defined "an injective $g$ from $A$ to $C$".  Combined with the obvious fact that $A$ is at least countable, such an injection is sufficient to prove that $A$ is countable.

@AnneBauval You are right that from $g$ you can derive the $A$ is countable, but the question asks for a specific cardinality.
$g$ gives that $|A|\leq \aleph_0$ , so one may say $|A|=m\in\mathbb{N}$.
I tried to build some function $\psi$ from $D : |D|=\aleph_0$ to $A$  in order to use CSB theorem and finish, but I faced a failure once again.

No, $|A|\ne m\in\Bbb N$. And again, the fact that $A$ is at least countable is obvious. Consider for instance the injection $h:\Bbb N\to A$ defined by $h(n)(k)=n+k$.

@AnneBauval Got it !! Thank you very much for your time and help !!

@mathcounterexamples.net Isn't your "one-to-one map from $A$ to $B$" just the identity map? I.e. $A=B$.

@AnneBauval Indeed, $A=B$, which is also simple to prove by double inclusion.

What I meant is that your post would be clearer if you replaced your third point with this.

@AnneBauval I wanted the OP to think about it rather than providing directly a solution!

Really? Then it was cruel (because rather misleading).
